# the max value of every 5 elements in one array with arbitrary length, python3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, max

I have a one-dimensional array. I want to calculate the max value of every 5 elements. The difficult part is the length of the array can be any value, either a multiple of 5 or not.

For example

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

The 1st 5 elements are 0 to 4, so the max value is 4; the 2nd 5 elements are 5 to 9, so the max is 9; the last part has only 3 numbers, 10 to 12, the max value is 12.
The expected results will be

```
result = [4, 9, 12]
```

Note that this specific example has 13 numbers, but in reality it can be any other values.

My first idea is, when there are exactly a multiple of 5 numbers (N*5), then I can reshape the arr to a 2 dimensional array (N rows and 5 columns), then use np.amax to get the max value of each row. For example, suppose N = 4

```
arr = np.arange(20)
arr = arr.reshape(arr.shape[0]/5, 5)
b = np.amax(arr, axis=1)
```

But the difficult thing is the length of the array can be non-multiple of 5.

How to efficiently do this? Thanks?

By the way, I am using Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
result = [max(arr[i:i+5]) for i in range(0, len(arr), 5)]
```

Comment: Might be worth to add this works with arbitrary length lists/arrays since the slicing notation doesn't raise IndexError.

Answer (score 0):

You can first slice your list in such a way that the length of the second list is between `0` and `len(original_list) - 1` (using modulo like `a[-(len(a) % 5):]`), and then take the maximum of the second list, and appending it to the result (which is a list of maximums you get from the method you suggested above) of the first list (which you get like `a[:len(a) - (len(a) % 5)]`).